# Reference for Algebraic Groups in Ergodic Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

It seems that the theory of algebraic groups is used in ergodic theory.  I was hoping someone could recommend an introduction to algebraic groups that

1. assumes a knowledge of commutative algebra
2. covers or begins to cover those aspects of algebraic groups which are useful in dynamics and ergodic theory
3. doesn't venture too far into abstractions that are unnecessary from the viewpoint of applications to dynamics.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to note is that the algebraic groups that come up in e.g. Ratner's theorem, or the recent work of Eskin--Mirzakhani, are *affine* algebraic groups.  These can be studied fairly concretely, and need less algebraic geometry than many other topics (for example, because at leasts for the basics you don't need to get into the study of projective varieties.)

Have you looked at Dave Witte Morris's [book on Ratner's theorem](http://people.uleth.ca/~dave.morris/books/Ratner.pdf)?  It summarizes some basics 
in a pretty succinct manner.

Comment: that kind of information is extremely helpful, since I'm not sure exactly what I need to know. thanks, I'll check out the Morris book.

Comment: So would it make sense, then, to restrict my studies to linear algebraic groups?  I noticed there are a few books on that subject.

Comment: @Timkinsella: Yes, I think this makes sense.  I would take something like DWM's notes as a guideline to what is needed, and then use one of the more substantial texts on linear algebra groups as a resource to look into as necessary.  One thing to be aware of is that some books on linear algebraic groups will go to quite a bit of effort to deal with problems that arise in the theory over fields of characteristic $p$ (although they may not always make it explicit that this is why certain arguments are written the way they are).  I don't think the char. $p$ theory will be relevant for you, ...

Comment: ... so I think it is good to be aware of it as a possible phenomenon, so that you can try to avoid it.  (Char. $p$ considerations are important in lots of other contexts, but certainly add length and complexity to some arguments.)

Answer (score 0):

A classical reference in this topic is Robert Zimmer's book [Ergodic Theory and Semisimple Groups](http://www.springer.com/birkhauser/mathematics/book/978-0-8176-3184-0). In his [notes](http://people.uleth.ca/~dave.morris/books/ZimmerCBMS.pdf) is an short appendix on  algebraic groups. There are also many other references about algebraic groups, e.g., the notes of J.S. Milne [here](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/LAG.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, I looked at the intro to Zimmer's book and it states that it does not develop the theory of algebraic groups and that a knowledge of algebraic groups is "technically" a prerequisite.   I'll look at Milne's notes, though.